# How to arrange date in R if date is in character?

Tags: r, date

Now I have a column called trending_month with character values:

```
'Jan 2018', 'Dec 2017', 'Feb 2018', 'Nov 2017'
```

How do I order them in ascending timeline to get this?

```
'Nov 2017', 'Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018'
```

As trending_month is in character, when I order it in ascending order, it arranges it according to alphabetical format.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert the values into date and then `order`. In base R, that can be done as

```
df[order(as.Date(paste(1, df$trending_month), "%d %b %Y")), ]

#  x trending_month
#4 4       Nov 2017
#2 2       Dec 2017
#1 1       Jan 2018
#3 3       Feb 2018
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, 
                 trending_month = c('Jan 2018','Dec 2017','Feb 2018','Nov 2017'))
```